# removing unwanted characters from string in php

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I'm using a database to store variables of user names and then access them using php. A form with post method is used to invoke a php file which access the database, retrieves all the user names and then compares them with the entered values. The user names are stored in $row['name'] variable and the name is stored in $photographer variable.

The problem is that there are some characters attached in string of variable $row['name'] when being accessed from db which I can't get rid of.

I thought using these variables directly might be causing some problems so I saved their values in other two variables. But the problem didn't go away.
Below is the php code:

```
//pin check module
$connection = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","members") or die(mysqli_error($connection));
$select_query_pin = "SELECT name, pin FROM members";
$select_query_pin_result = mysqli_query($connection, $select_query_pin) or die (mysqli_error($connection));
$total = mysqli_num_rows($select_query_pin_result);

$pin = $_POST['pin'];
$title = explode(",",$_POST['title']);
$url = explode(",",$_POST['url']);
$photographer = $_POST['photographer'];
$genere = explode(",",$_POST['genere']);
$entry = sizeof($title);

while ($total) {
    --$total;
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($select_query_pin_result);

    $name_sample = $row['name'];
    $test_sample = $photographer;
    // chop($name_sample);
    // chop($test_sample);
    preg_replace( "/\r|\n/", "", $name_sample );

    // for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($name_sample); $i++) {
    //  if ($name_sample[$i] == " ")
    //      echo 'true';
    // }

    var_dump($name_sample,$test_sample);
    if ($name_sample === $test_sample)
        echo 'true<br>';
    else 
        echo "false<br>";}
```

As you can see, I tried using the chop and preg_replace methods but it didn't work. When I check the strings using var_dump, it gives unequal lengths for equal strings. The html view of above code is this:[html output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/APTS1.jpg)

Is there a way to deal with it?

Comment: Note: The object-oriented interface to `mysqli` is significantly less verbose, making code easier to read and audit, and is not easily confused with the obsolete `mysql_query` interface. Before you get too invested in the procedural style it’s worth switching over. Example: `$db = new mysqli(…)` and `$db->prepare("…”)` The procedural interface is an artifact from the PHP 4 era when `mysqli` API was introduced and should not be used in new code.

Comment: Instead of cleaning up the unwanted characters after the fact, why not fix it in the database? These should be cleaned up on the way in, but you can repair the damage now with MySQL's `REPLACE` function.

Comment: Try wrapping the `$_POST` variables with the `trim()` function.  Like `trim($_POST['pin'])`.

Comment: Thanks for your solutions. I accidentally put those line breaks while adding data to database.